# How to reliably configure custom Spamassassin rules with Amavisd (on Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, spam-prevention, spamassassin, amavis

I've used Amavisd with Spamassassin for years... my configuration used to 'work' (though it may never have been "right") now, it appears as if /etc/spamassassin/local.cf configuration is ignored when spamassassin functionality is invoked by amavisd-new

I'm using a fairly vanilla configuration:

- Ubuntu (14.04.4 LTS)
- Postfix (2.11.0-1ubuntu1) - smtpd (and friends) as postfix
- Spamassassin (3.4.0) - spamd as root
- amavisd-new (2.7.1) - as amavis

Postfix, spamassassin and amavisd are all running as services, and mail is delivered with spamassassin scores.  The bayes database is in ~amavis/.spamassassin/bayes_*.

I am perplexed because it appears that the configuration I've placed in /etc/spamassassin/local.cf (a new score for a specific rule, for example) is ignored for messages processed by amavisd, but are not ignored when I run spamc, or "spamassassin -D -t" from the amavis account.  When I place equivalent configuration in ~amavis/.spamassassin/user_prefs - it also seems to have no effect on the results of amavisd-new processing.

I originally configured with reference to (something like) this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew

I've also considered these ideas (to no avail):
https://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#faq-spam

What I'd like to know is:

- Why are my custom "score" values, in /etc/spamassassin/local.cf, being ignored only when spamassassin is used via amavisd-new?
- Is there a neat way to get amavisd to use spamc (and, hence, ensure consistency)?

Answer (score 2):

#### 1st question:

First, and to be clear: The Spamassassin configuration files ARE used - they are not 'skipped'. I have seen others report that they are not used at all.

I know you saw this faq link, but the answer seems to be here. The FAQ may not spell out the exact "$sa_" (or other type) variables/etc you might need in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`, but it does go into great detail about how things are started and read. It would seem that you are probably simply being 'ignored' by amavis-new as far as SA's local.cf configuration. This is configuration-option dependent - some local.cf options may work - some may not.

But, you also have not mentioned what **exact** options (custom rules I assume?) you have under local.cf that are not being used (or ignored/undef'd by amavis-new).

https://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#faq-spam :

> SA does observe all settings in its configuration file, but not all of them have effect on the mail being checked, as amavisd-new does its own decisions based on spam score (hits) (so for example *required_hits* has no effect - use *tag/tag2/kill* amavisd-new settings instead), and does its own header editing, and body is not modified. Read on for related information.

Without more to go on as far as what specific SA local.cf options are ignored, this is your answer. You would need to post more specific info.

#### 2nd question:

Yes, you could hypothetically use SA as a separate content filter via Postfix/MTA/etc. **You are much better off staying with amavis-new** as the MTAs SA controller, though. You should be able to replicate what you need done under SA via Amavis-new configuration and/or `$sa_` variables/etc.

Note:

If running under Ubuntu (and probably Debian), there is also a global amavis-new Spamassassin user_pref/config file under: `/var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin/user_prefs`.
**I have added custom SA rules to this file - and they work fine.**

You can also kill main amavis process and try: `sudo amavisd-new debug-sa` to get output of what SA is doing/reading/compiling/etc. (Debian/Ubuntu name/location)

Example LOG shows amavis-new config reading some SA config files:

```
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: using "/etc/spamassassin" for site rules pre files
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/init.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/sa-compile.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v310.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v312.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v320.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v330.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v340.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v341.pre
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: using "/usr/share/spamassassin" for sys rules pre files
```

...

```
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: using "/etc/spamassassin" for site rules dir
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/65_debian.cf
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/local.cf
mail.example.net /usr/sbin/amavisd-new[30358]: SA dbg: config: using "/var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin/user_prefs" for user prefs file
```

Comment: Thanks, I could not figure out where the `/var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin/user_prefs` file actually was.

Comment: Yes, that should be the location of the global SA 'user' config file as installed by the Ubuntu amavisd-new repo pkg.

Answer (score 1):

amavisd-new uses its own config. These config files are located in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/`. In particular, in `20-debian_defaults`, `$sa_kill_level_deflt` is the "equivalent" to SpamAssassin's `required_score` (located in `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`).

In my experience, the score returned using amavis vs. using spamsassassin directly is never the same and I haven't figured out why yet, so when you are setting `$sa_kill_level_deflt` you'll need to figure out an appropriate value that may not be the same as `required_score`.

Answer (score 0):

After adding custom rules to local.cf, don't forget to run *spamassassin --lint* and to restart spamassassin and amavis daemon

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state, and confirming this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post if applicable?

Comment: You do NOT run Spamassassin as separate process if you are already running amavis-new. DO NOT DO THIS. You ONLY install Spamassassin - you do not start it. Amavis does that.